# Ruby on Rails : String not being converted into html tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using the following code as response to a ajax call but instead to forming a link , simple text is coming on the screen.

```
$('div.showcomment').text('<% @comments.each do |comment| %><%= comment.body %><%= link_to 'Delete Comment', articles_deletecomment_path(:id =>comment.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %><% end %>');
```

One sample text is as follows:
Delete Comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

It would be must better to place all your ERB code in a partial so you can nicely write ERB code (less confusing, more readable) and include your partial in your js file:

Partial:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.body %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete Comment', articles_deletecomment_path(:id =>comment.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

js.erb file (note the `j` before `render` to correctly escape for javascript content):

```
$("div.showcomment").html("<%= j render partial: 'path/to/file' %>");
```